# How to select a div preceeded by a script, preceeded by a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a structure like this:

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div>
      <div>Not tis one</div>
      <script>something</script>
      <div>THIS DIV</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Somehow `script + div` didn't work for me, possibly due to some extensions that I have or a similar reason.

I'm trying to give uBlock Origin a target for a "One more story" or whatever overlay at the bottom of the page [over here](https://medium.com/our-human-family/forget-stem-we-need-mesh-43ab6f6273cd).

Comment: Note that as an element that is not part of the rendered document, your CSS shouldn't rely on rules involving `script`. Your example shows "the last of a set of divs" so pseudo-selectors should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) depending on whether your code structure changes.

And if you want to make sure it's not too generic, you can specify the parent elements. With the HTML that you have, the CSS could look something like this:

```
#root div div:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

Quick Example:

```css
#root div div:last-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div>
      <div>Not this one</div>
      <script>something</script>
      <div>THIS DIV</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post code to 3rd party sites. Those links can die over time, making your answer useless. Always post your code right in your answer.

Comment: We post links to jsbin _all the time_ on SO, and this answer had both code and a jsbin link. No need to edit it into a snippet when the answer already has the code necessary, and a jsbin just as icing on the cake (with the benefit of jsbin of course that, unlike an SO snippet, people can edit-and-run them immediately. Something still sorely lacking when it comes to runnable snippets)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, while it works on the snippet, it does not on the linked page. I guess Medium does something wonky that fools uBlock from catching their passive-aggressiveness. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Ziatko Can you link to an example? If it's public, maybe the page itself, or recreate it in something like a JS Bin or CodePen?